# MediaCoderでAviSynthで作ったavsファイルから動画ファイルを作りたい。

Tags: 動画, avisynth-plus

Avisynth+をインストールして以下をavsファイルとして保存し、MHC-HCにDrag & Dropして動くことを確認できました。  
実際に動画ファイルとして保存したいと思い、MediaCoderにも同様にavsファイルをDrag & Dropし、AVIにEncodeしようと思い、ContenerはAVIにし、Formatを色々変えてみましたが、エラー14,9などがでてEncodeできません。  
丸々１日ネットで調べたのですがわからなかったので質問させてください。

以下のavsをMediaCoderで高画質(AVIもしくはm2tsもしくはh264)でEncodeする場合のMediaCoderの設定を教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
cli = ImageSource("C:\Users\aa\Pictures\camera.jpg",0,100,fps=60)
Animate(cli, 0, 149, "Crop", 0, 0, 200, 100,50, 0, 200, 100)
```

[バージョン]  
OS: windows7 32bit  
AviSynth+ r1576  
MediaCoder 0.8.33.5680